# Accessing nonlinear fit coefficients

Tags: fitting

I have performed a nonlinear fit onto a set of data according to the form 
$a+b\cos(2\pi x)+c\sin(2\pi x)+d\cos(4\pi x)+e\sin(4\pi x)$. How do I access the best fit parameters $a,b,c,d,e$, store them into a list perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the model

```
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b Cos[2π x] + c Sin[2π x] + d Cos[4π x] + e Sin[4π x],
          {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
```

you can extract individual parameters with, for example,

```
a /. model["BestFitParameters"]
(*    a real number    *)
```

or all of them at once in the order you like,

```
{a, b, c, d, e} /. model["BestFitParameters"]
(*    list of five real numbers    *)
```

I'd like to point out that your fit is actually a linear one, so you can do more efficiently

```
model = LinearModelFit[data, {1, Cos[2π x], Sin[2π x], Cos[4π x], Sin[4π x]}, x]
```

and get the list of best-fit parameters in the same order as the list of functions,

```
model["BestFitParameters"]
(*    list of five real numbers    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you name  `model=NonlinearModelFit[...]`

```
model["BestFitParameters"]
```

is what you are looking for I think.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I store the individual values of $a,b,c,d,e$ into lists?

Comment: `Values[nlm["BestFitParameters"]]` creates the list!